# Допустимы ли короткие однострочные ответы

Tags: поддержка

Последнее время стал частенько сидеть на stackoverflow и пытаться помогать людям с вопросами, но вечно возникает вопрос - куда отвечать лучше. С объёмными вопроса, где нужно полноценно ответить - вопросов не возникает, но, допустим, есть какой-то простой вопрос, на который можно ответить 1 строчкой и ссылкой на, например, metanit, офф.сайт чего-либо и т.д. - ответ на него писать в комментарий к вопросу или оформить в качестве ответа?

Далеко ходить не буду - последний пример: [Создание таблицы Xamarin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1409646/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-xamarin)

Comment: главное чтобы ответ не состоял _только_ из ссылки на какой-то сайт

Comment: Раньше кстати была такая фича (как минимум 2 года назад и как минимум на английском SO), что когда писал короткий ответ (если память не изменят то меньше 30-ти символов), то ответ отправлялся как комментарий к вопросу, а сейчас в принципе нельзя писать ответ меньше чем 30 символов. Так вот из-за этой фичи я себе мысленно сделал правило (с тех пор), что если мой ответ короткий очень, то пишу как комментарий

Comment: Хм, а мне нравится ваш принцип. Думаю, буду тоже его придерживаться)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы отсылаете на metanit (вообще не слышал до сегодня) или на офф доку, то вы подразумеваете какаю-то часть или абзац или пример кода, или на подобие. Так если сюда попал пользователь с таким вопросом и он может быть не один, может эту информацию перенести сюда в ответ?

С вашим примером, вы отсылаете на гитхаб, где все на английском. Ок, это может быть решением, но можно же тезисно вынести из доки и перевести полезную информацию: почему это - есть решение или почему это решение должно подходить к данному вопросу.

По большому счету, любой, даже самый простой вопрос можно растянуть на диссертацию. Если ваша цель действительно писать хорошие ответы, то обратите внимание на то, какие ответы здесь есть. Я некоторыми местными пользователями просто открыто восхищяюсь и прямо говорю им об этом.

Вот вам [пример ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460208/209304) на вопрос *Есть ли в Python оператор switch case?*. На момент написания ответа, можно было просто односложно ответить: "нет, нету, пользуйте if/elif" и это было бы верное утверждение. Однако, ответ содержит полную исчерпывающую информацию с примерами. И как итог высоко оценен сообществом.

В конечном итоге, если ваша цель помочь конкретному пользователю, дайте комментарий. Если вы понимаете, что вопрос шире или может быть полезен большому кругу лиц или просто вас заинтересовал => напишите [хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).